# How get a whole word with just a part of it?

Tags: java, string, substring

Example:
I have a String like this:

```
String query = "....COD_OP = 1 AND USER_DATA_SIGNIN = ...."
```

I need to get the whole word (`"USER_DATA_SIGNIN"`) when it have the `"_DATA_"` part.

In java is possible use some kind of substring inversely ? In this case I don't know how to get the `"USER"` part.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: "USER_DATA_SIGNIN" ?

Comment: You said that "*I need to get the whole word when it have the `"_DATA_"` part*" which would suggest that you want to find `USER_DATA_SIGNIN` but then you are saying that "*In this case I want to get the `"USER"` part*". Can you explain logic used here?

Comment: Exactly, in this case I want the whole word, which is "USER_DATA_SIGNIN".
I said that because I know how to get the right part of a String but I have no idea how to get the Left part

Comment: Then please update your question to clear this confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple imlementation, null checks are left to you:

```
    for (String string : query.split(" ")) {
        if(string.contains("_DATA_"))
        {
            System.out.println(string); // USER_DATA_SIGNIN
            System.out.println(string.split("_")[0]); // USER
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why I haven't thought this before :P

Comment: No problem, usually simplest solution is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pattern/Matcher classes which are responsible to regex mechanism in Java. You can create pattern which will represent word which have `a-zA-Z0-9_` characters (which can be represented by `\w` character class) before and/or after it like

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w*_DATA_\\w*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Comment: Nice alternative, works great too, thanks very much!